# How to create a https server on localhost

Tags: ssl, https, localhost

I followed the tutorial below to create a https server
https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/

and the program runs without errors

but when I can not open https://localhost:8000 in my chrome

it always get a `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

[image]

Comment: Checking that https works is part of developing a website these days. Humble developers use localhost. I think the question is a good one.

Comment: It may be a somewhat better fit to Webmaster.SE, since it is more about setting up the environment, rather than coding as such.

Answer (score 50):

Well one quick way to do this is with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/2).

It's really easy to use and only takes few secs to run. It is as simple as downloading your system version. Unzip and run `ngrok.exe`. It will open a command line type of window. Make sure your Apache server or the one you use is running.

Then to only listen on an HTTPS tunnel endpoint run the following

```
ngrok http -bind-tls=true site.dev:80
```

or on whatever port you need `https` to be installed.

Open browser and type `https://localhost/myApp` you will see it works.

And if you type `http://localhost/myApp` it also works.

Hope this is helpful to anyone for a fast solution.

Comment: This doesn't work. Error: `You may only specify one port to tunnel to on the command line, got 3: [http -bind-tls=true site.dev:80]`

Comment: what's site.dev here?

Comment: @Pavan It looks like that is referring to, and I'm quoting from the `ngrok --help` docs, "forward traffic to example.com:8000". Or in this case, "to site.dev:80". I instead used `ngrok http 3000 -subdomain=custom -bind-tls=true`, then went to `https://custom.ngrok.io` on my local.

Comment: It has solved my problems, I was trying in other ways and finally found a way to go forward locally...

Comment: Running this command on Windows gives `unknown flag: --bind-tls`, anyone know how to get past this?

Comment: @EricHasegawa without checking the ngrok docs I can imagine that running https is not free anymore, so you have to pay/subscribe.

Answer (score 13):

I use [Caddyserver](https://caddyserver.com/) with config like this:

```
:443
tls self_signed
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to do two things:

- generate a self-signed SSL certificate and
- add it to the trusted certificates

Managed to do this on a macOS like so:

- In order to **generate the SSL certificate**, run the follosing command in a terminal (according to the [instructions from Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/)):

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

- And to **add the certificate to the trusted certificates**, ran the following command (suggested on [this blog](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/adding-new-trusted-root-certificates-to-system-keychain/)):

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain" "/private/tmp/certs/certname.cer"
```

Comment: Sorry, is the downvote due to the macOS specific solution? I thought it would be straight forward to find the way to achieve that on other OSs, having an example. Should I make the response OS-independent?

Comment: If it's not about that, please let me know if I'm wrong so that I won't make the same mistake...

Comment: I get an error: Error reading file /private/tmp/certs/certname.cer - I don't seem to have a certs folder ?

Comment: The first command does not generate the `/private/tmp/certs/certname.cer` file expected by the second.

Comment: @StanJames and Matt I get the same error on Mac: `***Error reading file /private/tmp/certs/certname.cer
Error reading file /private/tmp/certs/certname.cer`

Answer (score 8):

If this is meant for testing and you don't need a valid cert (which seems to be the case since you're using "localhost") you can use a "self-signed" cert, just make sure to configure nginx to point to those.

I could explain the details, but there's actually a great post about that on Digital Ocean community tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

just be sure to adapt the port (443) if you want to listen on 8000.

Answer (score 7):

I finally set up my create-react-app https dev server

the reason why I'm doing this is to test device motion API on a mobile device.

install mkcert https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

```sh
brew install mkcert

mkcert -install
```

generate cert files.

```sh
mkcert -key-file ./.cert/key.pem -cert-file ./.cert/cert.pem "<LAN_IP_ADDRESS>"
```

use LAN IP address instead of "localhost", because we will open our https page on a mobile device that has connected to the same WiFi.

create a `.env` file to set env variables

```
HTTPS=true
SSL_CRT_FILE=./.cert/cert.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=./.cert/key.pem
```

start the dev server

```sh
npm start
```

last but not least, install the cert file on the mobile device, the `.pem` file generated by `mkcert` is located in `~/Library/Application Support/mkcert` in my case.

install cert file on an Android device

https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2844832?hl=en

install cert file on an iOS device

serve the `.pem` file on a static server, and open the file address on Safari

Answer (score 6):

A very simple way is using local-ssl-proxy

```
    npm i -g local-ssl-proxy

    local-ssl-proxy --source 3001 --target 3000
```

Comment: Is the idea here to run two processes in parallel? The simple HTTP server, and also the local-ssl-proxy?

Comment: Works fine, you just need to use `sudo` for installation.

`> sudo npm i -g local-ssl-proxy`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using node.js, then [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) has `-S` or `--ssl` with `-C` and `-K` to enable https.

Comment: Just tried this but http-server doesn't support passphrases so not sure how this would even work.

Comment: Keep in mind http-server is good for dev usage, but not necessarily good for production usage. Passphrases  is not a must for TLS/SSL mode.

Comment: I wasn't using for production, I had issue creating self-signing certificates without passphrase

Comment: Then it will just work as I have been using it that way for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by [Balloon Fight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554860/14597561) is absolutely what I was looking for and it works.
But the command mentioned didn't work for me, so here is what worked for me.

I am using Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (64-bit).

> Lubuntu is a lightweight Linux flavor using Debian, Ubuntu and LXDE as its base.

Steps for OSX would probably be similar. Steps for Windows and Ubuntu GNOME are also mentioned.

---

1. Go to [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) and create an account.
2. Download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) and install.

For Windows, just unzip the file and open it. It'll run in cmd.

For Ubuntu GNOME, you would probably be able to run the file directly in terminal.

For Lubuntu (or if previous didn't work for you).
Move the file as follows:

```
mv "path/to/ngrok" "/usr/bin/"
```

3. If the file had directly opened up in terminal or cmd. Copy and paste the command from your profile on ngrok into cmd or terminal. The command looks like this:

   `./ngrok authtoken <your_auth_token>`

If you are on Lubuntu, or if the file did not open directly in terminal. Change directory as follows:

```
cd "/usr/bin/"
```

And then copy and paste the command from your profile on ngrok into terminal. The command looks like this:

```
./ngrok authtoken <your_auth_token>
```

4. Run your server. Nodejs or what you usually use.
5. If you are still in the same directory as 'ngrok' file. Copy and paste the following command into terminal or cmd:

   ngrok http 3000 -host-header="localhost:3000"

Change `3000` to the port you are using for the local server.

If you are out of 'ngrok' file's directory. Open it up in terminal or cmd.

For Lubuntu, use the following command to change directory:

```
cd "/usr/bin/"
```

Then run the command:

```
ngrok http 3000 -host-header="localhost:3000"
```

Change `3000` to the port you are using for the local server.

[I got to know about this command from this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tg84mhnAhuA)

6. Copy and paste the HTTPS link, in the second 'Forwarding' row, to your browser.

The link looks something like this: [https://12fab5c82c57.ngrok.io](https://12fab15hjc57.ngrok.io)

**For the next time you are required to do it. Just repeat step 4, 5 and 6.**

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution that doesn't use ngrok because there is a 2 hour timeout on the dynamically created hostnames, and secondly, to bypass this requires a paid membership which is $20-25/month.

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
npx https-localhost
```

The https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-localhost package depends on having npm installed, of course, and takes care of generating the required certificate and trusting it locally.

To serve an arbitrary path on an arbitrary port, you might do something like:

```
PORT=10000 npx https-localhost ~/my-experiment
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a virtual host with https. if you are using a Wamp server, open SSL and create a virtual host. you can watch this video as well https://youtu.be/D5IqDcHyXSQ

uncomment and set path `openssl.cafile=` in php.in