# Axios error on changing the URL from http to https

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
const OTP_API = "https://192.168.4.10:8001/api/tatreports/getotp/";
const onNumberCheck = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://localhost:3005/api/is-user-exist/0${inputNumberValue}`
      );

      console.log(response);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setIsUserExist(true);
        // Send a notification when status is 200
        notification.success({
          message: ` سلام ${response.data.name}`,
          description:
            "کد احراز هویت برای شما ارسال شد. لطفا آن را وارد نمایید.",
        });
        setLoggedUserName(response.data.name);
        setLoggedUserAccessType(response.data.accessType);

        const otpRespons = await axios.get(`${OTP_API}${inputNumberValue}`);
        if (otpRespons.status === 200) {
          setValidationCode(otpRespons.data);
          console.log(otpRespons.data);
        }else{
          notification.error({
            message: `مشکلی پیش آمده`,
            description: "لطفا ارتباط با سرویس پیامکی را چک کنید و یا با پشتیبانی تماس بگیرید",
          });
        }
      }else if(response.status === 403){
        notification.error({
          message: `این شماره اجازه دسترسی ندارد`,
          description: "لطفا با پشتیبانی تماس بگیرید",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        // The request was made, but the server responded with a status code
        const statusCode = error.response.status;
        console.error(`Request failed with status code: ${statusCode}`);
        notification.error({
          message: `این شماره اجازه دسترسی ندارد`,
          description: "لطفا با پشتیبانی تماس بگیرید222",
        });
      } else if (error.request) {
        notification.error({
          message: `No response received from the server.`,
          description: "لطفا با پشتیبانی تماس بگیرید",
        });
        console.error("");
      } else {
        notification.error({
          message: `Error setting up the request:`,
          description: `${error.message}`,
        });
      }
    }
  };
```

in this code i get the same, it works when i use http for localhost or my Windows server but when i change it to https i get this error: AxiosError: write EPROTO 483E0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

Comment: I assume your localhost doesn't support https?

Comment: my windows server only response to https requests but when i change my links from http to https i get the error :  AxiosError: write EPROTO 483E0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

Comment: I'm guessing that accessing the same problematic URL directly via your browser address bar will also fail, with the same error ...? Then your problem isn't really related to axios in the first place. You need to go and fix your broken SSL setup then.

Comment: SSL has versions, and some of them are no longer supported by Microsoft. You should check, which SSL version are you using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a domain name using a valid SSL certificate in your server.

https://DomainName/api/is-user-exist/0${inputNumberValue}

Comment: i added this code const userServerOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem"),
};

const userServerHTTPS = https.createServer(userServerOptions, userServer);

userServerHTTPS.listen(userServerPort, () => {
  console.log(`user server is running on port ${userServerPort} HTTPS...`);
});
in my server side and its working now, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access Local IP Addresses with **https://**

You have to use **http://** for development. Then when you deploy it to any web server there you can use https after installing SSL.

```
like: https://example.com/
```

Comment: Not entirely true, it is possible to get a certificate and have https locally. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677457/how-to-create-a-https-server-on-localhost